# Xcode Parse Issue Expected '>', Expected ')'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
}
```

Errors I'm getting are: Parse Issue Expected '>', Expected ')'

I am a beginner to Objective C, can anyone point out where the error is and explain please.

Thanks

Comment: you're mixing objective-c and swift. Where you have `NSDictionary<...>` remove `<...>` and you should be left with `...change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void *)...`

Comment: Ok thanks it worked. :)